# displaying selected text in Qwebview using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, qwebview

i am trying to display the selected text in QwebView browser with javascript. but i dont know why its not working..
here is my code:-

```
frame = self.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
frame.evaluateJavaScript("alert("+"'"+frame.getSelection().toString()+"'"+");")
```

when i am running this code it shows me the error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GUI-Test.py", line 32, in slotshowxpath
frame.evaluateJavaScript("alert("+"'"+frame.getSelection().toString()+"'"+");")
AttributeError: 'QWebElement' object has no attribute 'getSelection'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you name a variable `frame`:

```
frame = self.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
```

does not mean it's a QWebFrame:

> Each QWebPage object contains at least one frame, the main frame,
>   obtained using QWebPage.mainFrame().

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebframe.html

> A QWebElement object allows easy access to the document model,
>   represented by a tree-like structure of DOM elements. The root of the
>   tree is called the document element and can be accessed using QWebFrame.documentElement().

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebelement.html

If you look in the [QWebElement class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html), there's no method named `getSelection()`.

Comment: i know that but i want to know that how can i  get the selected element using javascript. i also know that we can get the text using self.selectedText but i am looking for the element.

Comment: @rickyrana, `frame.evaluateJavaScript("alert(window.getSelection().toString())”)`